# Inline JavaScript in React app

Tags: facebook, reactjs, tracking

I want to include a script tag with some inline JavaScript on some pages of an Isomorphic React application.

The script tag in question, is Facebook's conversion code:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/conversion-pixel-code-migration

```
<script>
(function() {
  var _fbq = window._fbq || (window._fbq = []);
  if (!_fbq.loaded) {
    var fbds = document.createElement('script');
    fbds.async = true;
    fbds.src = '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbds.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(fbds, s);
    _fbq.loaded = true;
  }
})();
window._fbq = window._fbq || [];
_fbq.push(['track','1234567890',{'value':'10.00','currency':'USD'}]);
</script>
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" alt="" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?ev=1234567890&cd[value]=10.00&cd[currency]=USD&noscript=1" /></noscript>
```

As this code is only on certain pages of the application, I was hoping to store this chunk of code in a variable and pass through the application for conditional rendering.

However, if I include something like this in a .jsx file:

```
var code = <script>function() {var test = "test";}</script>;
```

Then I get a parse error:

```
SyntaxError: test-page.jsx: Unexpected token (10:31)

> 10 | var code = <script>function() {var test = "test";}</script>;

    at Parser.pp.raise (/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:425:12)
```

Removing the 'var' fixes this:

```
var code = <script>function() {test = "test";}</script>;
```

...though I'm not sure why, and it doesn't really solve the issue as I need to be able to use var declarations.

Are there any instructions on how to include inline JavaScript in a `<script>` tag as a variable in React/JSX? Any advice on how I could achieve this?

(I am using the pixel only tracking for now)

Comment: Try using [react-helmet](https://github.com/nfl/react-helmet). It's a manager for the `<head>` portion of sites. You can use it on your `App.js` to set items in the `<head>` site wide and also more specifically to components for specifics. I'm using it to manage Facebook Pixel and Open Graph data.

Answer (score 1):

You really should not use JSX for something that isn´t JSX...and removing "var" is a very bad idea too. Assuming/hoping you are using CommonJS or even ES6 modules, just create a separate module for the Facebook code and require/import it whenever you need it. Although, React is for SPAs, so you would only need to load it once, at the beginning, in your main component. Either way, you should create a module for it. Without JSX, easy to use in other projects.